# Unable to parse a complex language with regex and Scala parser combinators

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to write a parser for a certain language as part of my research. Currently I have problems getting the following code to work in a way I want:

```
private def _uw: Parser[UW] = _headword ~ _modifiers ~ _attributes ^^ {
  case hw ~ mods ~ attrs => new UW(hw, mods, attrs)
}

private def _headword[String] = "\".*\"".r | "[^(),]*".r

private def _modifiers: Parser[List[UWModifier]] = opt("(" ~> repsep(_modifier, ",") <~ ")") ^^ {
  case Some(mods) => mods
  case None       => List[UWModifier]()
}

private def _modifier: Parser[UWModifier] = ("[^><]*".r ^^ (RelTypes.toRelType(_))) ~ "[><]".r ~ _uw ^^ {
  case (rel: RelType) ~ x ~ (uw: UW) => new UWModifier(rel, uw)
}

private def _attributes: Parser[List[UWAttribute]] = rep(_attribute) ^^ {
  case Nil   => List[UWAttribute]()
  case attrs => attrs
}

private def _attribute: Parser[UWAttribute] = ".@" ~> "[^>.]*".r ^^ (new UWAttribute(_))
```

The above code contains just one part of the language, and to spare time and space, I won't go much into details about the whole language. _uw method is supposed to parse a string that consists of three parts, although just the first part must exist in the string.

_uw should be able to parse these test strings correctly:

```
test0
test1.@attr
"test2"
"test3".@attr
test4..
test5..@attr
"test6..".@attr
"test7.@attr".@attr
test8(urel>uw)
test9(urel>uw).@attr
"test10..().@"(urel>uw).@attr
test11(urel1>uw1(urel2>uw2,urel3>uw3),urel4>uw4).@attr1.@attr2
```

So if the headword starts and ends with `"`, everything inside the double quotes is considered to be part of the headword. All words starting with `.@`, if they are not inside the double quotes, are attributes of the headword.

E.g. in test5, the parser should parse `test5.` as headword, and `attr` as an attribute. Just .@ is omitted, and all dots before that should be contained in the headword.

So, after headword there CAN be attributes and/or modifiers. The order is strict, so attributes always come after modifiers. If there are attributes but no modifiers, everything until `.@` is considered as part of the headword.

The main problem is `"[^@(]*".r`. I've tried all kind of creative alternatives, such as `"(^[\\w\\.]*)((\\.\\@)|$)".r`, but nothing seems to work. How does lookahead or lookbehind even affect parser combinators? I'm not an expert on parsing or regex, so all help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `"[^@(]*".r` has anything to do with your problem. I see this:

```
private def _headword[String] = "\".*\"".r | "[^(),]*".r
```

which is the first thing in `_uw` (and, by the way, using underscores in names in Scala is not recommended), so when it tries to parse `test5..@attr`, the second regexp will match all of it!

```
scala> "[^(),]*".r findFirstIn "test5..@attr"
res0: Option[String] = Some(test5..@attr)
```

So there will be nothing left for the remaining parsers. Also, the first regex in `_headword` is also problematic, because `.*` will accept quotes, which means that something like this becomes valid:

```
"test6 with a " inside of it..".@attr
```

As for look-ahead and look-behind, it doesn't affect parser combinators at all. Either the regex matches, or it doesn't -- that's all the parser combinators care about.